# Exception handling mechanism in Angular application

Tags: .net, angular, exception

I want to create a web application with angular 5 . What are the different and new ways of handling exceptions in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Please [check the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know how to use this site efficiently.

To answer you question: as Angular uses Typescript, error handling is [basically the same.](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/exceptions.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . May i know the ways of logging error but not for client side in angular

Comment: You mean logging client errors in the backend? Create a custom service, which sends http PUTs to a logging server with the errors, for instance.

Comment: I want to log the errors generated in my code( mvc, web api) . I mean the business logic errors which is generated

Comment: not sure about what you mean.
Angular is a frontend framework, which works by running a thick client application in the browser of the client. 
The usual way is that you run a second application, a backend in a server, which communicates with the multiple instances of the Angular app trough the web.
So handling those errors, can be achived in the backend. If you have a REST api interface, then there. The Angular application is the "View" layer.

Comment: Thank you. any material or link showcasing how to log errors in rest api interface

Comment: it depends on the framework you want to use for the backend. 

An example for angular error handling is [here](https://hackernoon.com/global-http-request-error-catching-in-angular-486a319f59ab).